# run package ros-usarsim error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi i try to install this package and i dont know how run it
http://sourceforge.net/p/usarsimros/code/ci/master/tree/usarsim_inf/

i try

```
~$ roslaunch usarsim_inf usarsim.launch
[usarsim.launch] is neither a launch file in package [usarsim_inf] nor is [usarsim_inf] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198980/run-package-ros-usarsim-error/) by [ksmksam](https://answers.ros.org/users/20913/ksmksam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-12-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-12-09**:
Did you make that **usarsim_inf** package??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it seems that you have not make(Compile) your usarsim_inf package.
follow these steps to make the usarsim_inf package:-

1. Go into the usarsim_inf folder using `cd` command
2. set the environment variable path using this command:

   export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:`pwd`
3. run the following command:

   ```
    rosmake usarsim_inf
   ```

then verify your package is successfully made or not by following command:

```
rospack find usarsim_inf
```

it will show the path of your folder and then you will be able to use this package.

---

Originally posted by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) with karma: 351 on 2014-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0